# R5RS - How to test procedures that use `read` operation

Tags: scheme, r5rs

Is it possible to test procedures that use the `read` operation?

ex.

```lisp
(define (foo prompt)
  (display prompt)
  (read))
```

I tried to use `write` but `read` seems to create a block so that the `write` is only run after I enter something manually

Comment: You could define your own procedure `(read)` to return whatever value you want. e.g. `(define (read) "Hello!")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the internal `read` in your code, that call will read not from the standard input but from your file itself, because the reader that converts the input file into a list of s-exps will use the same read function.  So, yes, you can use it if you redefine it, otherwise the result is harder to anticipate.  Here is an example of `read.scm`:

```
(define (foo m)
  (display m)
  (read))

(display (foo "input:"))

200

(newline)
```

Example of use:

```
% mit-scheme --silent < read.scm
input:200
```

The value `200` will be read by the function call, it will not be returned in the final list that represents the code.

To define your own `read-keyboard` functionality you can take as model [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scheme_Programming/Input_and_Output#Reading_from_the_keyboard).

Comment: Just a note: I'm marking this as answered because it works with what information I gave in the question, but it doesn't work in my specific set-up (Dr Racket - R5RS)

Comment: @Alter Racket is multi-language.  If you set it on r5rs it should work.

Comment: perhaps I'm confused, but it seems the `read` with racket and r5rs does seem to use standard input (ie. it gives me a text input box)

Comment: I cannot help because I used racket only for limited purposes, mainly focusing on other aspects of r6rs, not on i/o interface.

Comment: @Alter Which OS are you using? Are you using Racket r5rs through DrRacket or through the command line?